# Was Luminara ever arrested by the Empire?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, star-wars-rebels

**spoilers for TCW and Rebels**

In season 1 of *Rebels,* the *Ghost* crew believes that Jedi Master Luminara Unduli may be alive and held in captivity by the Empire, as observed from a holo they see of her being arrested and led away by troopers.  When Kanan and Ezra find her, however, they learn that the Empire only has her corpse and she has already died.  The Inquisitor says that she "died with the Republic," implying this happened roughly 15 years ago when Order 66 was issued.  But the holo shows Luminara in prisoner's garb and chains, so was she ever arrested?  And did the Inquisitor later kill her in her cell?  Or was the holo never real, and Luminara died in Order 66?  Do we know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [Star Wars: Battles that Changed the Galaxy](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Battles_that_Changed_the_Galaxy), Unduli was indeed captured during the Battle of Kashyyyk.

p81 (italics mine):

> **Aftermath**
> As night fell on the battlefield, operations shifted to hunting down Separatist stragglers and fugitive Jedi. *Unduli was captured and taken into custody, where she ultimately perished*, but Yoda escaped offworld with the help of friendly Wookies and went into exile. Vos' fate remains unknown.

Based on some searches online, I do believe that the authors extrapolated this from Unduli's appearance in Star Wars Rebels – Rise of the Old Masters, but it is now canon.